# Simulated sphere shape data based on normal distribution

Tags: r

I'm clueless on below question. Any help is appreciated please.
"Simulate data with n=1000 observations and p=3 covariates -- all random variables from standard normal distribution.  Create two category class variable assigning all observations within a sphere with radius of 1.5 centered at 3D zero to one class category and all others -- to the second".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 2D example to get you going...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
```

Sample x & y coords from normal distribution (default mean = 0, sd = 1)

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
```

Calculate distance from centre (0,0)

```
df$r = sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
```

Assign to category

```
df$category <- ifelse(df$r < 1, "in", "out")
```

Plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = category)) + 
    geom_point() +
    coord_equal() + 
    annotation_custom(grob=circleGrob(r=unit(1,"npc"), gp = gpar(fill = NA)), xmin=-0.5, xmax=0.5, ymin=-0.5, ymax=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: As it's looks like a homework question, I'll let you work that out :-)